# standard streams in git hook when running commitizen

Tags: git, commitizen

i have a [prepare-commit-msg](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg) git hook that performs runs interactively. it works well when git commit is executed, but when committing using [commitizen](https://commitizen-tools.github.io/commitizen/) the prepare-commit-msg git hook does not show any output and thus cannot be used interactively.

how can i make prepare-commit-msg to act the same when it runs with and without commitizen?

```bash
$ cat .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
#!/bin/sh
read -rep "what is your input: " -i "foo" input
```

Comment: You forgot to show your hook. How are we supposed to help troubleshooting, when we don't know what is being executed?